# Mixing position and weight rank to sort document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ranking

Let's consider the following list of documents (here sorted):

```json
{ product: "foo", position: 1, weight: -150 }
{ product: "bar", position: null, weight: 200 }
{ product: "baz", position: null, weight: 100 }
{ product: "boo", position: 4, weight: 0 }
{ product: "baa", position: null, weight: 90 }
```

I'd like to build a query that uses the position as the actual position, not as a rank (meaning product 10 must be at the 10th position) and the rest of the products should be ordered by a second field weight, including in empty positions (like in the previous example).

I didn't find how to achieve the position thing, do some of you maybe know a plugin that handles that?